# floating point operations in Linux using expr utility

Tags: linux, bash, arithmetic-expressions, expr

Not sure, but I'm unable to get this.

```
38/1024 = 0.0371
```

When i'm performing:
`echo "scale=2; 15 / 0.0371" |bc`, it gives me result:

```
404.31
```

But, when i', performing :
`echo 'scale=2; 15/(38/1024)' |bc` , the output is:

```
500.00
```

Why there's difference in results.

I need the output to be `404.31` from the second command.

Thanks.

Comment: This is because your floating point precision is different in second case. In first case you are using ```0.0371``` for division whereas in second case you are using ```38/1024``` with precision for 2 decimal points which gives ```0.03```. So essentially your actual command in second case is ```echo "scale=2; 15 / 0.03" |bc```, hence different output. If you want the same output as first use scale as 4 like ```echo "scale=4; 15/(38/1024)" |bc```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realized the concept of `scale` here..Many Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your floating point precision is different in second case.

In first case you are using `0.0371` for division whereas in second case you are using `38/1024` with precision for 2 decimal points which gives `0.03`.

So essentially your actual command in second case is

```
echo "scale=2; 15 / 0.03" |bc
```

hence different output.

If you want the same output as first use scale as 4 like

```
echo "scale=4; 15/(38/1024)" |bc
```

Comment: You don't get the same output, you must use echo "scale=4;a=15/(38/1024);scale=2;a/1"|bc or with dc echo '4k15 38 1024/2k/p'|dc -f -